# How to patch rails built in model generators?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, generator, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in the situation where I want to add another field to every model that I create with `rails generate model MyModel`. By default it will get assigned an `ID` as well as timestamps for `created_at` and `updated_at`.

How can I reopen this generator and add a field `deleted_at` to the default generator?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, but you could create your own generator, possibly calling the original one and then adding your own fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a local version of the generator file that is created after you run the generator command. Here's the original just for reference: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb

You would need something like this:

```
class <%= migration_class_name %> < ActiveRecord::Migration[<%= ActiveRecord::Migration.current_version %>]
  def change
    create_table :<%= table_name %><%= primary_key_type %> do |t|
<% attributes.each do |attribute| -%>
<% if attribute.password_digest? -%>
      t.string :password_digest<%= attribute.inject_options %>
<% elsif attribute.token? -%>
      t.string :<%= attribute.name %><%= attribute.inject_options %>
<% else -%>
      t.<%= attribute.type %> :<%= attribute.name %><%= attribute.inject_options %>
<% end -%>
      t.datetime :deleted_at # <------- ADD THIS LINE
<% end -%>
<% if options[:timestamps] %>
      t.timestamps
<% end -%>
    end
<% attributes.select(&:token?).each do |attribute| -%>
    add_index :<%= table_name %>, :<%= attribute.index_name %><%= attribute.inject_index_options %>, unique: true
<% end -%>
<% attributes_with_index.each do |attribute| -%>
    add_index :<%= table_name %>, :<%= attribute.index_name %><%= attribute.inject_index_options %>
<% end -%>
  end
end
```

and then patch the generator class and point it to wherever you saved that file ^

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Generators # :nodoc:
    class ModelGenerator < Base # :nodoc:

      def create_migration_file
        return unless options[:migration] && options[:parent].nil?
        attributes.each { |a| a.attr_options.delete(:index) if a.reference? && !a.has_index? } if options[:indexes] == false
        migration_template "#{ PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE.rb }", "db/migrate/create_#{table_name}.rb"
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Might take a little tweaking, but that should do the trick. You can also just pass that field in when you run the generator:

`rails g model YourModel deleted_at:datetime`

Comment: No problem and glad that will work for you. I know a lot of people who have mixed feelings about monkey-patching, but it gets the job done. :) Oh man, you're at 2,999. I'd love to be the vote that puts you over 3K, but I already upvoted the question :)

Comment: Welcome @NickM Severin ;)